# How to use implode a column from an array of stdClass objects?

Tags: php, arrays, implode, csv, stdclass

I have an array of `stdClass` objects and I want to build a comma separated list using one specific field of all those `stdClass` objects.  My array looks like this:

```
$obj1 = stdClass Object ( [foo] => 4 [bar] => 8 [foo-bar] => 15 );
$obj2 = stdClass Object ( [foo] => 16 [bar] => 23 [foo-bar] => 42 );
$obj3 = stdClass Object ( [foo] => 76 [bar] => 79 [foo-bar] => 83 );

$a = array(1=>$obj1 , 2=>$obj2 , 3=>$obj3);
```

And I want to implode on `foo` of all the `stdClass` objects in that array to create a comma separated list.  So the desired result is:

```
4,16,76
```

Is there any way to do this with implode (or some other mystery function) without having to put this array of objects through a loop?

Comment: maybe if you overload the toString() method of the object.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and `implode()`...

```
$a = array_map(function($obj) { return $obj->foo; }, 
               array(1=>$obj1 , 2=>$obj2 , 3=>$obj3));

$a = implode(", ", $a);
```

Comment: This works and is cleaner than a loop, unfortunately I am finding that a foreach loop performs better. I'm getting similar results with array_reduce :(  Guess I'll just stick with the foreach loop.

Answer (score 14):

With PHP 7.0+ you can use `array_column` for this.

```
echo implode(',', array_column($a, 'foo'));
```

Comment: Works only, if foo is declared public.

Comment: @JochenJung Can you have non-public properties in a StdClass object?

Answer (score 11):

This is actually the best way I've found, it doesn't seem to be answered here properly as the array of objects should be able to handle dynamic size.

```
$str = implode(',', array_map(function($x) { return $x->foo; }, $a));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can actually set [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) on the class as suggested by Ray, but you don't need to iterate through the `array` first. [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will directly call the `__toString()` function of the objects (which also works with associative arrays, btw).

Answer (score 6):

A very neat solution for this is the [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) function, that reduces an array to a single value:

```
$str = array_reduce($a, function($v, $w) {
    if ($v) $v .= ',';
    return $v . $w->foo;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo implode("','",(array)$data->stdArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way would be to create an ID indexed array and then call implode on array_keys:

```
$a = array();
$a[4] = stdClass Object ( [foo] => 4 [bar] => 8 [foo-bar] => 15 );
$a[16] = stdClass Object ( [foo] => 16 [bar] => 23 [foo-bar] => 42 );
$a[76] = stdClass Object ( [foo] => 76 [bar] => 79 [foo-bar] => 83 );

echo implode(', ', array_keys($a));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the best you can do is iterate through, call tostring() on the object and put the results in a new array to call implode on.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 1-level object, this worked for me.

```
function implodeObjValues($glue, $obj) { 
    $s = "";
    foreach($obj[1] as $n=>$v) {
        $s .= $glue . $v;
    }
    return substr($s,strlen($glue));
}

function implodeObjLabels($glue, $obj) { 
    $s = "";
    foreach($obj[1] as $n=>$v) {
        $s .= $glue . $n;
    }
    return substr($s,strlen($glue));
}
```

Could include a by-type multi-level process, but I didn't need that yet.
Hope this helps.

Handy for converting MySQL object back to array.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost",$usr,$pw,$db);
$row = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
$a = implodeObjValues("|",$row);
```